# Error when running SQL stored procedure coversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @i varchar(13)
DECLARE @Year varchar(30)

SET @i = 2
SET @Year = 2013

SELECT SUM(CAST([totalAfterMultiplier] as money)) as 'totalAfterMultiplier' FROM [postfinanceAfterMultiplier] 
                    WHERE CAST([ORDER] as date) >= '01/'+@i+'/'+ @Year +'' AND CAST([ORDER] as date) <= '31/'+@i+'/'+ @Year +''
```

I am getting this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

All values in the database are `varchar(50)`

I have looked at the other posts and can't seem to get it working

Thank you all for your help

Comment: take a look here: `SET @i = 2` and here `'31/'+@i+ '/'+ @Year`

Comment: This would lead to the 31st of february, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't store dates as varchar.
2. if you want to convert to date from string `'dd/mm/yyyy'`, use explicit format 103, like  `select convert(date, '01/12/2013', 103)`. See other formats here - [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply, what should I store the dates as? 'Date' but this will change the format from E.G 01/12/2013 to 2013-12-01

Comment: you should store dates as `date` type, and if you want to show it like  `'dd/mm/yyyy'`, just use convert in your select.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the following solution works:

```
DECLARE @i varchar(13)
DECLARE @Year varchar(30)


SET @i = 2
SET @Year = 2013



SELECT SUM(CAST([totalAfterMultiplier] as money)) as 'totalAfterMultiplier' FROM [postfinanceAfterMultiplier] 
                    WHERE MONTH([ORDER]) = @i AND YEAR([ORDER]) = @Year
```